# Retrieving data from database to dropdownlist using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I can already data into the database, but I cannot retrieve it from the database into the dropdownlist. Can anyone help me out?

My view:

```
<body>

 <div id="container">


      <?php echo form_open('form/myform'); ?>

       <select class="form-control" >
        <?php 

        foreach($groups as $row)
        { 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->school.'">'.$row->school.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
       </select>

     <div id="addother">
       <?php  echo form_input(array('id'=>'addother_input', 'name'=>'school', 'placeholder'=>'Enter name of school...')); ?>
       <input type="submit" id="add" name="submit" value="+" />
     </div>

     <?php echo form_close(); ?>
   </div>
```

My Controller:

```
    function myform(){
    $data['title'] = "myform";

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->load->model('school_model');

    $sdata['school'] = $this->input->post('school');

    $this->school_model->addItem($sdata);

    $this->load->view('myform');

}

function drop() {
    $this->load->model('school_model');

    $data['groups'] = $this->school_model->getAll();

    $this->load->view('myform', $data);
}
```

My Model:

```
 function getAll() {

   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT school FROM tblschool');

   return $query->result();

}


function addItem($sdata){

   return $this->db->insert('tblschool', $sdata);

}
```

I'm really confused on how to retrieve data from the database into the dropdownlist. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: As I see from your view code, you have not retrieved any thing from the database!`$options = array(
            'school' => $row->school ,
            'addother' => 'Add other...'
          );`

Comment: Can you teach me how?

Comment: I have edited my post. Can you please take a look at it?I still can't fetch the data from the database into the drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accessing `form/drop` to generate the view? If you want to access this via `form/myform` you will have to change myform to include the call to `$this->school_model->getAll();`

```
public function myform()
{
    $data['title'] = "myform";

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('school_model');

    if($this->input->post()){
       $sdata['school'] = $this->input->post('school');
       $this->school_model->addItem($sdata);
    }

    $data['groups'] = $this->school_model->getAll();
    $this->load->view('myform', $data);
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code but the data that I have input still won't appear in the drop down list. It only adds blank rows.

Comment: Try adding a vardump in the controller after calling `getAll()`. `var_dump($data['groups']);` to see what you are getting from the database. Ideally you should see an array of stdClass objects with `school` properties.

Comment: This is what appears:     array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#18 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "320" ["school"]=> string(5) "AMACC" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#19 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "321" ["school"]=> string(7) "adfasdf" } }

Comment: If that's the case then it should work. Since you really seem to having trouble, add another var_dump but this time in the view. If you're code is exactly as you have included above, add another `<?php var_dump($groups); ?>` before the opening select tag in the view. It should be exactly the same as the one you just got now. I think at this point you can debug the problem you are having by yourself.

Comment: This is what appears after I put the var_dump before the select tag:      array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#18 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "322" ["school"]=> string(8) "asdfasdf" } }

Comment: it adds a blank row in the dropdownlist but no value.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much! I guess I was just blind enough to not notice it. lol